# Problems using CIFilter in iOS 14 widget

Tags: widget, ios14, cifilter

I wrote a small CIFilter routine that works fine in a SwiftUI app:

```
func applyFilter(_ image: UIImage) -> UIImage {
    if let filter = CIFilter(name:"CIComicEffect") {
        filter.setValue(CIImage(image: image), forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        
        if let outputImage = filter.outputImage  {
            let context = CIContext()

            if let cgimg = context.createCGImage(outputImage, from: outputImage.extent) {
                return UIImage(cgImage: cgimg)
            }
        }
    }
    
    return image
}
```

But when I use it in iOS 14 widget,

```
Image(uiImage: uiImage)  // works fine
```

but

```
Image(uiImage: applyFilter(uiImage))  // return nothing
```

Does not work.

PS: upon further testing it seems that CIComicEffect does not work but CISepiaTone did. Any idea why?

Comment: I wonder if you maybe don't have access to the GPU when creating the widget. Have you tried setting up the context like this? `let context = CIContext(options: [.useSoftwareRenderer: true])`

Comment: Thanks Frank! Unfortunately it does not work.